# Change menuitem action using xpath or inherit

Tags: xpath, odoo, odoo-12

I would like to change my existed menu items action from another module.

My Menu Item:

```
<menuitem name="MyRootMenu" id="main_menu"
          action="old_action"/>
```

I would like to change this action id through another module using xpath.

Answer (score 1):

Koray

Menu entries are usually defined with the `menuitem` XML tag (e.g. for Project>Configuration.

```
<menuitem name="menuName" id="mod_id.menu_id" ... />
```

You can `inherit` in this way,

```
<record model="ir.ui.menu" id="base.menu_definitions">
    <field name="name">Configuration</field>
</record>
```

You can also check reference here [Source Code](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/addons/project/security/project_security.xml#L18)

Comment: Your answer is great but you should put the name of the action field instead of name, for new odoo developers that don't understand what this code do